# Round / smooth the end points of curve in geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to recreate an image below in geometry nodes.

[image: img1]

I'm having trouble getting the ends of the spiral curve to be rounded any ideas?  See nodes setup below.

[image: img2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

[image]

You can solve your concrete problem as follows:

1. First put all your base curves into one package with `Join Geometry`. This makes them easier to handle.
2. Then create a *UV-Sphere* and remove the parts you don't need. Only a quarter of the sphere is needed here.
3. Convert the base curves to points with the node `Curve to Points`, because this way you get the rotation at the ends. And here we only need the endpoints in each case.
4. You can then rotate the instantiated objects at the ends accordingly. The node `Modulo` selects here every second instance.
5. In the last step, create your mesh with `Curve to Mesh` (and possibly merge the parts with `Merge by Distance`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this helps you?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure why this question was closed since the link posted doesn't even mention rounding the end points (it deals with rotation)...strange

Comment: be aware: my solution creates "inside" geometry. So it would be cleaner if you just take one half circle and rotate it accordingly...but if you are not looking for perfection...then my solution works ;)