# Lighting up a letter from one end to the other - Like a 3D "progress bar"

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, lighting

I would like to animate a 3D letter gradually filling with light from one end (kind of like a 3D "progress bar" that goes around corners).

I would also ike to ensure that the light has a rounded tip as it travels around the letter.

I have used a curve to create the letter "U" for the below example, and I have made a mock up of how I would like the light to progress around the letter (it's just using multiple static meshes, and is not animated in any way).

I would like to ask for some ideas on ways to animate the light smoothly progressing around the curve. I have limited experience with using curves in projects.

Any ideas are appreciated and thankyou in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268252/round-smooth-the-end-points-of-curve-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round / smooth the end points of curve in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268252/round-smooth-the-end-points-of-curve-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: Thankyou Chris and Duarte, this might be helpful for rounding the edges, indeed! I still have the issue of figuring out how to animate light actually following the curve and filling the letter.

Comment: Geometry nodes might help. Look into animating a *Curve Trim* node

Comment: [This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243415/35559) might help you with that